# Css Animate library makes site to crash in Safari and Chrome using iPad

Tags: css, ipad, properties

I have a site using the [Animate](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library which crashes in Safari and Chrome using iPad.

I [found](http://snippets.khromov.se/slow-performance-and-crashes-on-ios-safari-and-chrome/) that webkit browser in iPad doesn't support some css properties include in this  library, then I started by removing this one out from the libray:

**-webkit-backface-visibility: ....;**

But it seems that there are more to be deleted. How can I know which ones are not supported in webkit browsers?

Comment: Have you tried prefixr.com to see if it can find better prefixes for the specific browser?

Comment: @Nima how can I know which are the prefixes I have to change?

Comment: prefixr will automatically set the prefixes, it's a JavaScript's plug-in that you can download here: http://prefixr.com. You can add the plug-in to your page and see if that resolves the issue.